# What is the datatype we will give for enum assigned variables?

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

What datatype I have to use for direction in typescript or angular ? Fill that XXXX.

Note : There will be no error even if you didn't mention the datatype or mention **any** datatype. For coding standards, I don't want to use **any** datatype.

```
enum Directions {
  Up,
  Down,
  Left,
  Right
}

let directions : xxxx = Directions;
```

Comment: If you don't specify type, it will be inferred as `typeof Directions`

Comment: If you still want to specify it explicitly: `let directions: typeof Directions`

Comment: so whether we have to give like "let direction: typeof Directions = Directions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Aleksey L. for the answer..

let directions: typeof Directions = Directions

Answer (score 0):

Just use name of enum as type, like [in Typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html):

```
enum Response {
    No = 0,
    Yes = 1,
}

function respond(recipient: string, message: Response): void {
    // ...
}

respond("Princess Caroline", Response.Yes)
```

Comment: my scenario is not like this , I clearly stated that I have to write a statement like "let directions : xxxx = Directions;"